# Codeception's see() method with Yii2 does not display the entire contents of the page

Tags: testing, yii2, phpstorm, bdd, codeception

I'm testing a PHP(7.2.1) system that uses the Yii2 framework, and for that, by default I'm using codeception.

When writing functional tests, several methods are not working as expected. Among them is the see() method that should fetch text passed as a parameter on the specified page. In my case the see() method searches only in the side menu of the application, not in the page as a whole.

I would like help to try to solve this error, I already researched the documentation of the framework but could not find anything related to my problem.

Here is the code for the functional tests I wrote and the error displayed.

Test class:

```
<?php

use app\models\Usuario;

class FirstTryLoginCest
{

    public function _before(\FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnRoute('site/login');
    }

    public function submitFormSuccessfully(\FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->submitForm('#login-form', [
            '#usuario-username' => 'Fulano',
            '#usuario-password' => '12345678'
        ]);
        $I->see('Mural');
    }

    public function internalLoginByInstance(\FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $admin = \app\models\Usuario::findOne(33);
        $I->amLoggedInAs($admin);
        $I->amOnPage('gestor/mural');
        $I->see('Fulano');
    }

}
```

Error displayed:

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.4.1
Powered by PHPUnit 7.1.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Functional Tests (2) -------------------------------------------------- 
✖ FirstTryLoginCest: Submit form successfully (0.14s)
✖ FirstTryLoginCest: Internal login by instance (0.07s)
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Unit Tests (0) -------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Time: 464 ms, Memory: 16.00MB

There were 2 failures:

---------
1) FirstTryLoginCest: Submit form successfully
Test  tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:submitFormSuccessfully
Step  See "Mural"
Fail  Failed asserting that  on page /index-test.php?r=site%2Flogin
-->  Username cannot be blank. Password cannot be blank. Lembrar no 
próximo acesso Entrar Esqueci minha senha Copyright &COPY; 2018 Nome da 
empresa 
--> contains "Mural".

Scenario Steps:

3. $I->see("Mural") at tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:19
2. $I->submitForm("#login-form",{"#usuario- 
username":"Fulano","#usuario-password":"12345678"}) at 
tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:16
1. $I->amOnRoute("site/login") at 
tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:10


---------
2) FirstTryLoginCest: Internal login by instance
Test  tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:internalLoginByInstance
Step  See "Fulano"
Fail  Failed asserting that  on page /gestor/mural
-->  Toggle navigation Fulano Fulano Fulaninho Administrador 
Perfil Sair Fulano Gii Debug Same tools Gii Debug Level One Level Two 
Level Two Level Three Level Three Nome da empresa &COPY; 2018   Nome da 
empresa Software Versão 9.0 β string(1) "0" 
--> contains "Fulano".

Scenario Steps:

4. $I->see("Fulano") at tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:29
3. $I->amOnPage("gestor/mural") at 
tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:28
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you generate the main content of the page using javascript code or load it in iframe?
You can find contents of the page as seen by Codeception in tests/_output/ directory.

Comment: Neither option, the content is loaded in the template using regular HTML.